# Match strings which do not start or end with

Tags: regex

How can I test a string if it begins with "files/" and/or ends with ".js"?

Examples:

- test/test2/test.html --> true
- **files**/test2/test.html --> false
- test/test2/test **.js** --> false
- **files**/test2/test **.js** --> false

So far I have this regular expression: `(^(?!files\/)).*?((?!\.js)$)`

This works for "files/" but not for ".js".

**Edit:**
Sorry for the misunderstanding. The string should only match if a string does NOT start with "files/" and does NOT end with ".js".

Comment: Actually it's ColdFusion which is, as far as I know, using Java Regex. Edit: Ups, sorry, I need it for the IIS URL-Rewrite module.

Comment: You are using negative lookaheads, which ensure your result does **not** contain either of those.

Comment: People have spent time helping you: if the other answers were also useful, please up-vote them.

Comment: @RoManiac helping them out and get nothing as if they are paying us.

Comment: Flavors like JavaScript, Ruby and Tcl do not support lookbehind at all, even though they do support lookahead. You might be lucky that IIS URL Rewrite Module ships with Perl 5 compat/ECMAScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last negative should be a look behind not a look ahead, At the point of the test you've already read the `.js`

```
^(?!files\/).*(?<!\.js)$
```

Comment: Ah, better. Mine is just a hacky fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex that does what you need.

```
(^(?!files\/)).*((?!\.js).{3}$)
```

You were checking if the last character did not have ".js" in front of it, which is always true.

Comment: What if for some reason the filename was "xx"

Comment: Yeah that is a problem, although it is unlikely in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
!/^files\/|\.js$/.test('files/test2/test.js') -> false
!/^files\/|\.js$/.test('files/test2/test.html') -> false
!/^files\/|\.js$/.test('test/test2/test.js') -> false
!/^files\/|\.js$/.test('test/test2/test.html') -> true
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The string should only match if a string does NOT start with "files/" and does NOT end with ".js".

Comment: @android just invert the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = /^files\/.*|.*\.js$/;
alert(re.test('your-strings'));
```

**EDIT**

No worries, just invert the result:

```
var re = /^files\/.*|.*\.js$/;
alert(!re.test('your-strings'));
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The string should only match if a string does NOT start with "files/" and does NOT end with ".js".

Comment: No worries, just invert the result:
var re = /^files\/.*|.*\.js$/;
alert(!re.test('your-strings'));
And please vote UP if this is useful...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^(files/.*|.*\.js)$
```

Since you dont want strings ending or starting with files and or js,use the above regex and do this

```
if(/*regex matches the string*/)
{
//you dont need this string
}
else
{
//you do need this string
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The string should only match if a string does NOT start with "files/" and does NOT end with ".js".

Comment: @android still the regex is valid..check if it matches with the above regex and if it doenst match that is the string you need.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with the IIS URL-Rewrite module, since it's just a XML file... I'll check this.